# How do I sort custom date in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a column named `date`, in which are memorialized romanian dating system. For instance: 12 decembrie 2013, it means 12 decembre 2013, or 11 aprile 2014 it means 11 april 2014.

This way does not sort correctly:

```
SELECT `date` FROM articles ORDER BY DATE(`date`) ASC
```

I'm asking you if is there any way to sort my column after date? The idea is that somehow my date system to be converted after universal system as sort it after it. But I don't know how?
**UPDATE**
The months

```
ianuarie  => january
februarie => february
martie    => march
aprilie   => april
mai       => may
iunie     => june
iulie     => july
august    => august
septembrie => september
octombrie  => octomber
noiembrie  => november
decembrie  => december
```

UPDATE. Thx to exussum  this is the solution:

```
SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE
(
REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(
                                REPLACE(
                                    REPLACE(
                                        REPLACE(
                                            REPLACE(`date`,'ianuarie','january'),
                                        'februarie', 'february'),
                                    'martie', 'march'),
                                'aprilie','april'),
                            'mai','may'),
                        'iunie','june'),
                    'iulie','july'),
                'august','august'),
            'septembrie','september'),
        'octombrie','october'),
    'noiembrie','november'),
'decembrie','december')
,'%d %M %Y') DESC ;
```

Comment: Usually one would store a date in a database *without* a format. Incoming dates would be parsed and outgoing ones formatted.

Comment: My problem is that i did not build the database , i just have a column with this format, and i have to sort it

Comment: Just create a new column with correct dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its going to be slow, but you could use a combination of str_replace and str_to_date

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

It may also help if your server is set up correctly as you can forget about replacing the month names

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/locale-support.html

example

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`date`,'%d %M %Y');
```

or

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(`date`,'ianuarie','january'),'februarie', 'february'),'martie', 'march')    ,'%d %M %Y');
```

You would need 12 replaces to make it work though, It may be easier to switch locale and just use the former code

You should be able to do it on a per session basis

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lc_time_names

Comment: there is a lot of stuff here that i did not hear about yet. can you post me a sample or something?

Comment: ok. but how should i continue:D THIS doest not work :SELECT `date` FROM articles ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(`date`,'decembrie','december'), REPLACE(`date`,'martie','march')  ,'%d %M %Y');

Comment: updated it for the first 3 months, you should be able to continue in a similar way

Answer (score 0):

Use a MySql User-Defined Function and apply it on the Date field . 
You can also use a detailed CASE statement, but that may not be the most optimal choice from a clean-code point of view.

Comment: ok, i dont know what does it mean user defined function, but if you post a sample or example, its a high probabily that i would understand better. srry im not so good at mysql

Comment: Not necessarily in the date context, but this one gives a basic idea of what a UDF is, and how to use it.  Also, check which version of MySql you are using and whether it supports UDFs. 

http://www.sqlexamples.info/PHP/mysql_udf1.htm

I can't write a specific date example for you right now, I have step out out for dinner, but if you are unable to catch the above example, let know, I'll try to write one when I'm back.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to put the correct number of month instead of it's romanian label; ianuarie -> 1 ... decembeie -> 12. This way you might not need a formatter and is understandable in any language.